# How accurate is Google Home's voice recognition, especially where the speaker has a thick accent?

Tags: google-home, voice-recognition

I'm thinking of purchasing [Google Home](https://madeby.google.com/home/).

In the past I have always had issues due to a 'broad Yorkshire accent' with voice recognition systems. I'm concerned that if I purchase Google Home, my accent will prevent the device from accurately recognising my voice.

How well does Google Home's voice recognition work with thicker accents (especially those that deviate strongly from standard English)? Are there statistics comparing Google Home's performance to other voice recognition systems?

Answer (score 8):

If you have an Android phone, try to use the speaking option of the keyboard or try "Ok Google" and ask something.

I suppose Google uses the same speech recognition engine on all its platforms...

Answer (score 4):

[Google home can be trained](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1788/is-it-possible-to-train-the-google-home-device-for-different-styles-of-pronunc/1800) by saying several times the key word Hello, Google.

I am not sure how this takes effect in different pronunciations, but for now this is the only way to teach GH anything.

Train it again:

> unfortunately you have to unlink your ID that's having trouble and then add it back in (scarier than it sounds).
>
> It's over by the devices at the top of the screen.   Just unlink it from the device it's having a problem with.
>
> Then I had to exit the app and go back in and a popup came back asking to add it and retrain.

[Source](https://support.google.com/googlehome/forum/AAAAXWcshA0AtdiileVZww/?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

This interesting and engaging Youtube video by WIRED shows [8 People Test Their Accents on Siri, Echo and Google Home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNx0huL9qsQ).

The test is based on 4 questions, asked by each person, to each device under test. Google Home emerges better among the 3 devices at understanding variations in accents followed by Siri and Echo.