# Is it possible to train the "Google Home" device for different styles of pronunciation?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant, voice-recognition, smart-assistants

My English pronunciation and accent is different from how American or British English is spoken. I suspect this is contributing to misses for the *Google Home* device.

Is there a way that I can train the *Google home* device generally or specifically for the words that I know it has tendency to miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what you can do for training by yourself is to retrain the device for your voice. You'll say consecutive times the wake words as they are prompted by the app.

I found a post stating you should tell the wake words all around your home to get different conditions better taken in care. My claim is that the same would apply if you imitate little bit differently your accent in every time.

Disclaimer: This procedure goes through the wake words, so I am not 100% sure if this is enough to catch all nuances.

In other hand Google asks the words so many times it is sufficient, so maybe they know when they get enough data.

Idea about different locations [from Google Support](https://support.google.com/googlehome/forum/AAAAXWcshA0AtdiileVZww/?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, Alexa asks for more than wake words.

- My son an I had accounts linked to it. After using it for a few months, all of a sudden it chimed up and asked me which one I was and then asked me to say a few things so that it could tell us apart.
- I also asked it to recognise my wife's voice even though she doesn't have an account.

One of the ways to retrain it is

- Open Alex App
- Press on `More`
- Press on `Settings`
- Press on `Your Profile & Family`
- Press on `Voice ID`
- Press on `Delete Voice ID`
- Set it up again.